# How to push the uinavigationcontroller into another uinavigationcontroller

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationcontroller, pushviewcontroller

Currently i have an application that uses uinavigationcontroller but hides the navigationbar only in root view and i want to use this application as external library in some application and push this entire application as one menu item.

But when i try to push this application in navigation stack it hides the navigation barand i am not able come to my previous list.

How to show the back button in this case and How to push one uinavigationcontroller in some other navigationcontroller?

please help me in this issue.

Answer (score 1):

The navigationController is applicable throughout the application.So,what u need to do is simply hide the navigation bvar in RootViewController and show it on the next view.This solves your problem.

Comment: Hi, but my problem is navigation bar is hiding in one of my external library and I am missing the back button

Comment: may you have not properly push the view.please once check it. are you pushing view at current place. and also you can put back button by left bar button.(coding)